# How can I see which values exists in Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

Given an array (in Bash), is there a command that prints the contents of the array according to indices?

Something like that:  `arr[0]=...` , `arr[1]=...` ,...

I know that I can print it in a for loop, but I am looking for a command that does it.

Comment: `declare -p arr` -- at a bash prompt, enter `help declare`

Comment: @glennjackman I haven't been able to find a duplicate - would you mind answering this so it can be referred to in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an array with contiguous indices starting at `0`:

```
$ arr=(one two three)
```

And non-contiguous indices:

```
$ declare -a arr2='([0]="one" [2]="two" [5]="three")'
```

You can print the values:

```
$ echo ${arr[*]}    # same with arr2
one two three
```

Or, use a C style loop for `arr`:

```
$ for (( i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++ )); do echo "arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}"; done
arr[0]=one
arr[1]=two
arr[2]=three
```

But that won't work for `arr2`.

So, you can expand the indices (contiguous or not) and print index, value like so:

```
$ for i in "${!arr2[@]}"; do echo "arr2[$i]=${arr2[$i]}"; done
arr2[0]=one
arr2[2]=two
arr2[5]=three
```

Or inspect it with `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'
```

Which also works if the array has non-contiguous indices (where the C loop would break):

```
$ declare -p arr2
declare -a arr2='([0]="one" [2]="two" [5]="three")'
```

Note: A common mistake is to use the sigil `$` and thinking you are addressing that array or named value. It is the unadorned name that is used since the sigil will dereference and tell details of the name contained instead of that name:

```
$ k=arr
$ declare -p $k
declare -a arr='([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")'  # note this is 'arr' , not 'k'

$ declare -p k
declare -- k="arr"
```

Since `declare` with no arguments will print the entire Bash environment at that moment, you can also use utilities such as `sed` `grep` or `awk` against that output:

```
$ declare | grep 'arr'
arr=([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three")
k=arr
```